# UPDATE STATEMENT GETTING STUCK

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing a performance issue with an update statement. It takes too long to update, but when I perform a select on that updating table it completes very fast.

```
UPDATE mo
   SET mo.RNCNEID    = ts.RNCID,
       mo.SiteNEID   = ts.SiteID,
       mo.SectorNEID = ts.SectorID
FROM COPS_UMTS_HUAWEI.PER.tHuawei_CELL_Ncell_DY_HR AS mo
 INNER JOIN COPS_UMTS_HUAWEI.Aggregation.tsector   AS ts  
     ON mo.rncname      = ts.rncname
    AND mo.cellid       = ts.cid
    AND ts.VendorID     = 6
    AND ts.TechnologyID = 2
WHERE mo.RNCNEID IS NULL;
```

After running the below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   COPS_UMTS_HUAWEI.PER.tHuawei_CELL_Ncell_DY_HR WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  RNCNEID IS NULL;
```

...it completes very fast.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: You might want to check for large 'children' tables with foreign keys pointing to the columns you are trying to update.

Comment: Another possibility that I've seen before is an indexed view that makes use of the table being updated.In those cases, the view has to be re-run.
Also what@ScottHodgin mentioned, checking any foreign key constraints can be problematic as well.

Comment: Try it again, but this time remove the `with(nolock) ` form the query. If it doesn't end fast so you are getting slowed down by locks

Answer (score 1):

> It takes too long to update but when I do select on that updating table its completes very fast .

If the `UPDATE` query is taking a long time, but the `SELECT` part is fast when run on its own, then one possible reason is that the `UPDATE` is getting *blocked* due to incompatible locks being held by another session.

You can check for this while `UPDATE` query is running by, for example, running [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/docs/):

```
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive;
```

[image: screenshot of sp_whoisactive results showing wait_info with lck_m_x waits]

In this screenshot, I'm trying to run an `UPDATE` in session_id 57, but it's blocked by another session that's holding locks that my query needs.  You can see this in the `wait_info` and `blocking_session_id` columns, which show `LCK_M_X` waits (which is an exclusive lock, usually required by another `UPDATE` query running) and 53 (the other session that is holding the lock).

> After running the below query...Query completes very fast .

Running that `count(*)` query will likely make sure all of the pages needed for the query are in memory (meaning it will be faster, because they won't have to be read from disk first).  This probably just masking the blocking issue, as the blocking query finishes faster when the pages are in memory.

Comment: I have verified there is no blocking while update query is executing .I want to know why update is not able to get required data in Cache but select is able to do so ?

Comment: Version used - SQL SERVER 2008 R2,
table tHuawei_CELL_Ncell_DY_HR  has around 26 million records,
table tsector has 40K records.

It seems to me after doing select with (nolock) and predicate same as update query statistics is created , which is helping the update statement 
but I am not sure about it how a executing query can consider the new statistics and change the plan to execute the statement efficiently .

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach used in a similar situation.  An update was hanging when updating 1 attribute in 1 row of a 30 row table.  This table was a foreign key reference from some much larger tables.  Diagnosed it by:

1. open Activity Monitor and look at the Processes section
2. right-click on the update process
3. choose Show Live Execution Plan

In my case, saw the row counts on the referencing tables updating in real time on the Live Execution Plan.  This was a hint that, even though the column in question had nothing to do with the foreign key relationships, SQL was scanning those tables (don't know why).

The update through 'Edit top 200 rows' timed out.  Ran the update in a query and it completed ... but took 4 minutes.